# Аутентификация приложения Angular2 на identity server4

Tags: angularjs, angular2, identityserver4

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой стороны подойти к аутентификация приложения Angular2 на identity server4? Спасибо!

Comment: identity server4?

Comment: Да, identity server4

Answer (score 0):

Пройти официальную документацию quick start. Angular 2 - это spa. Необходимо использовать Implicit Flow.
Ссылки которых должно хватить.

https://elanderson.net/2017/07/identity-server-usage-from-angular/

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html